# Unable to access values of scenario outline examples

Tags: php, selenium, behat, gherkin

I'm trying to access my scenario outline examples within my step definition but I'm unable to.

**This is my feature and scenario...**

Feature: verify email
Background: Given I am on “https://www.somewebsite.com”
Scenario Outline: Confirm email address

Given I fill in the email field with “”
When I submit the form
Then I should see “”

Examples:
|      |  |
|                   | email is required |
| invalid@          | email must be valid |
| valid@gmail.com   | success page |

**This is my step definition...**

```
/**
 * @Given /^I fill in the email field with “(.*)”$/
 */
public function iFillInTheEmailFieldWith($email_value)
{
echo("email =====");
    echo($email_value);

}
```

- The output is it print the header name .

Instead of getting the actual values of the email (e.g. invalid@, valid@gmail.com,etc.) it's giving me the literal header name `<email_value>`.

What am i doing wrong here?  Please help...

Comment: clearly this was translated, and makes little sense in English.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here I think the scenario file is not written correctly here.
Below is the correctly way. You have to specify the column names in quotes like `"<email_value>"` in order to access the value in step def.

```
Feature: verify email Background: Given I am on “https://www.somewebsite.com”

Scenario Outline: Confirm email address
Given I fill in the email field with "<email_value>"
When I submit the form Then I should see "<message>"

Examples:
  | email_value     | message             |
  |                 | email is required   |
  | invalid@        | email must be valid |
  | valid@gmail.com | success page        |
```